# Rest Template:Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type when we got xml response, not bind to JAVA object

Tags: java, xml, spring, resttemplate

In Spring app, I am calling third party services, I am sending XML request and getting XML response to me, I got the XML response properly when not able to parse that response into Java Object, I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.drf.fundingapi.model.response.pojo.Fmxresponse] and content type [text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:884) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:868) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:622) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:498) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.drf.fundingapi.apiclient.RestTemplateBase.performRequest(RestTemplateBase.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.drf.fundingapi.apiclient.ApiClient.performPost(ApiClient.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.drf.fundingapi.service.FundingService.getAccountBalanceRequest(FundingService.java:255) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.drf.fundingapi.controller.FundingController.getGeneralOperationBalance(FundingController.java:100) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
```

I am making xml request as follows,

```
Fmxresponse fmxresponse  = apiClient.performPost(url, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, requestData, new HashMap<String, String>(), Fmxresponse.class);
```

Fmxresponse object as follows,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "fmxresponse")
public class Fmxresponse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4050582129050191456L;
    @XmlElement(name = "response")
    private Response response;
    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [response = " + response + "]";
    }
}
```

In App.Config

```
   @Bean
        public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Following XML response we receive,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fmxresponse>
    <response>
        <error>
            <code>0</code>
            <mesg></mesg>
        </error>
        <category>generaloperation</category>
        <function>balance</function>
        <result>
            <balance>
                <type>current</type>
                <amount>50,000.00</amount>
            </balance>
            <balance>
                <type>available</type>
                <amount>50,000.00</amount>
            </balance>
        </result>
    </response>
</fmxresponse>
```

Can any one have any idea, what's going wrong here?

Comment: is this resolved? if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your response is coming back as `text/html`, not `text/xml`.

```
... and content type [text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1]
```

You should create a `HttpMessageConverter` to handle this content type or configure your `RestTemplate` to handle the response properly.

See [Force Spring RestTemplate to use XmlConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038529/force-spring-resttemplate-to-use-xmlconverter) for an exammple of how to configure your `RestTemplate` instance.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but still I am getting,  
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.String] and content type [application/xml]

Comment: That is a pretty different error. The one in your question was about reading a response, and this one is about writing a request. It says you cannot write a `String` as `application/xml`. What did you add and where are you getting this error?

Comment: I have added
@Bean public RestTemplate getRestTemplate()
{
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxbMessageConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
mediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
jaxbMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
messageConverters.add(jaxbMessageConverter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
return restTemplate;
}

Comment: Are you using the same `RestTemplate` to make the request?

Comment: Yes. RestTemplate using to make request.

Comment: Try also adding `mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);`

Comment: Still not working. Its pretty simple but still not working strange!

Comment: @user1310038 Running into something similar.. how did you resolve this?